# how to prevent showing json data to user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, http-caching

This url  returns `json`

```
https://example.com/product/product_name.json // returns json document
```

and

```
https://example.com/product/product_name
```

returns html which calls the above JSON url internally with jquery, It structure it and present the data nicely.

In controller i am doing caching

```
def product
  expires_in 1.day , public: true
  render json: @product
end
```

Now the problem is if the user visit directly to `https://example.com/product/product_name` at very starting, it loads `html` but when he visits agains, he is seeing `json` data.

Is there anyway to prevent this or control it so user may not see `json`.

PS: `http` caching works best for us, i know other caching techniques.

**UPDATE** Rendering based on format isn't working. I guess it is because the request isn't hitting the server because of `http_caching`. Anyway, this is what i m doing in `application_controller`.

```
before_filter :intercept_html_requests, :unless => :not_format_html? 
private

def not_format_html?
 request.format != Mime::HTML
end

def intercept_html_requests
  render('homepage/index')
end
```

Comment: why dont you render based on requested format?

Comment: I think that rendering on the requested format should work. Can you show us your routes for it ? And what you wrote in your controller when you tried ?

Comment: above code is minimal code, the actual code is too vast. and the route looks like this `match "/product/:product_url" => "products#product"` th